# Exclude a specific package from react metro bundler when building

Tags: node.js, react-native, webpack

I have a library that requires:

- rnkata.js when running in react native
- webkata.js when running in a browser
- nodekata.js when running in node

This hack works OK as long as I'm only targeting node/web:

```
if (getEnv() == "node") {
  eval('require')('nodekata')
} else {
  require('webkata')
}
```

But once I started targeting mobile, metro bundler would complain "webkata not available":

```
if (getEnv() == "node") {
  eval('require')('nodekata')
} else if (getEnv() == "mobile") {
  require('rnkata')
} else {
  require('webkata')
}
```

Obviously, I can't use the same eval hack - or I break either webpack or RN.  Is there some documentation on how to manage this situation? IE: how can i suppress bundling or interpreting of a 'require' call by platform.

Is there a "suppress by module name" feature?   Or some other way to have a platform-specific module?

Comment: Where is code this in your application? You could use different webpack entries for each platform, and build them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Metro recently added support for Optional imports.  It should be available in React Native v0.63.0.  See [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/120) issue and [this](https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/511) PR for more details.

You could also consider doing naming the files to show which platforms they support. For example:

```
index.js - web version
index.native.js - android & ios only version
index.android.js - android version
index.ios.js - ios version
```